# How to update the Flash Player?

Tags: 10.10, flash

I've installed Flash Player 10.1 to do some tests, now I can't go back to the lastest version (10.3).

I've gone to the [Flash download page](http://www.playerversion.com/), downloaded and installed "APT for Ubuntu 10.04+", but it's still showing "10.1" at [playerversion.com](http://www.playerversion.com/). In both Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate Flash player in the Software Center and uninstall it (`adobe-flashplugin`?). Next, install `flashplugin-installer`. After the installation has completed, restart the browser.

You must have installed it manually. Running `locate libflashplayer.so` on my system yields:

```
/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
/usr/share/ubufox/plugins/libflashplayer.so
/var/cache/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
```

Check if there is a `libflashplayer.so` file in `~/.mozilla/plugins`. If existent, delete it.

Comment: Done, but it's still showing "10.1". Now I just uninstalled it and restarted the browsers, and it's still showing "10.1", I think I need to uninstall it somewhere else..

Comment: Please check `~/.mozilla/plugins` and compare the result of `locate libflashplayer.so` with mine.

Comment: Cool, both Mozilla and Chrome were using the Mozilla plugin. Now it was successful uninstalled. Thanks!

Comment: run `locate libflashplayer.so` and delete it from all locations, then reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [Flash-Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/) firefox extension; very simple and pain free.

Comment: This worked for me, although it is a security gamble since it requires sudo permission for the script that gets run.